# 'super' object has no attribute 'form_valid' (Django)

Tags: python, django

I think the reason that I got this error maybe because I didn't use `FormMixin` and form_class in the detailView. I have tried it but my form will not run without `current_class_pk` (I added it inside my AttendanceForm using `kwargs.pop`) so I have to use `get_context_data` to pass the pk of detailview to the form.

How can I fix this? or Are there anyway other ways to pass detailview pk to the form_class?

view.py

```
class Class_detailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    login_url = '/'
    model = Class
    template_name = "attendance/content/teacher/class_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        class_pk = self.object.pk 
        print(class_pk)
        context = super(Class_detailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['attendance_form'] = AttendanceForm(current_class_pk=class_pk) # pass data to form via kwargs 
        return context

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('class_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if request.method == "POST":
            attendance_form = AttendanceForm(request.POST, current_class_pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
            if attendance_form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(attendance_form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.teacher = self.request.user
        form.instance.attendance_class = self.object
        form.save()
        return super(Class_detailView, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['student',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_class_pk = kwargs.pop('current_class_pk')
        super(AttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_student = Class.objects.get(id=current_class_pk)
        self.fields['student'].queryset = current_student.student
```

error i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 73, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/annexar-attendance/attendance/views.py", line 199, in post
    return self.form_valid(attendance_form)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/annexar-attendance/annexar-attendance/attendance/views.py", line 205, in form_valid
    return super(Class_detailView, self).form_valid(form)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'form_valid'
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message with traceback…

Comment: [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#detailview)'s don't have a form, `FormView`'s do

Comment: @Sayse Inside my detailView I want to have another form and that form uses a model which has a `manytomanyfield` with other model. So I want to filter the manytomantfield with current detailview id.

Comment: Thats fine but you need to use something with a FormMixin or use the mixin yourself.

Comment: @Sayse If i use FormMixin I dont know how to pass the detailView's pk into the form. Do you know how to pass pk into the form within form_class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I want to use form inside DetailView I really need to have `FormMixin` and set the form_class. So I fixed it by override `get_form_kwargs` method and remove `get_context_data` from the view.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(Class_detailView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['class_pk'] = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    return kwarg
```

and inside the `forms.py` all I need to do is passing the `class_pk` into the constructor argument.

```
def __init__(self, class_pk, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AttendanceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    current_student = Class.objects.get(id=class_pk)
    self.fields['student'].queryset = current_student.student
```